# Binary search with a list containing string arrays won't work

Tags: c#, methods, binary-search

I have made a method for a binary search but when I am trying to use it I get the message "Cannot implicitly convert type int to string[]".

Here is my method for the binary search:

```
private static int BinarySearch(List<string[]> myBlog, string searchedWord1)
        {
            int left = 0;
            int right = myBlog.Count - 1;

            while (left <= right)
            {
                int mid = (left + right) / 2;

                if (searchedWord1.Equals(myBlog[mid][0]))
                    return mid;
                else if (searchedWord1.CompareTo(myBlog[mid][0]) < 0)
                    right = mid - 1;
                else
                    left = mid + 1;
            }
            return -1;
        }
```

And here is what I have started coding in the main method:

```
case 7:
                            Console.WriteLine("Which title do you want to search for?");
                            string binarySearchInput = Console.ReadLine();
                            string[] searchedWord1 = BinarySearch(myBlog, binarySearchInput);
                            
                            break;
```

When I put binarySearchInput as the second argument I get the error message: "Cannot implicitly convert type int to string[]."

What should I change?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You cannot binary search a List of strings for a containing string. Binary search requires some assumptions to be applicable to the input, which they are not here. (Did not DV)

Comment: Is there any reason to write this yourself? It would probably be better to write a custom comparer and call [`List.BinarySearch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=net-7.0), especially if you are just using the first value in each array as the comparison object.

Comment: @JonasH that would require the searched input to be sorted, though. I really don't see how that would make sense in OP's domain.

Comment: Then I probably don't understand how binary search works. I have made a console application that works as a blog and wanted to implement a binary search to search for the title of the blog posts. I have sorted the list with bubble sort.
The reason I am writing it myself is because it is an assignment in the beginner programming course I'm taking.

Comment: @Fildor, Well, obviously any binary search will require sorted input. But that should be trivial to do if you have a comparer to compare the objects.

Comment: So, on each new Blog Entry you sort the List<string[]> with a bubble sort? And also, when any title is changed?

Comment: @Fildor Yes, exactly.

Comment: @sam_the_man I would highly recommend to create a class to represent your "blog". So you can have properties like `.Title`, `.Body` etc, that make the code much easier to read. In principle your code looks fine, but it is super easy to make of-by-one errors in code like this, so you need to test it well to ensure you have handled all edge cases.

Comment: Ok, well. It's a "school" project after all... Just be aware that you wouldn't do anything like that in a "real" project. But again, there you would use a database and proper classes etc ... I guess this was about "having implemented a binary search at least once" ;D

Answer (score 2):

You're returning an int from the function but have declared a `string[]` type on searchedWord1.

```
private static int BinarySearch(List<string[]> myBlog, string searchedWord1) {
...
}
...
string[] searchedWord1 = BinarySearch(myBlog, binarySearchInput);
```

Notice the `string[]` on the `searchedWord1` variable. I believe just swapping the type of `searchedWord1` to `int` should work:

```
int searchedWord1 = BinarySearch(myBlog, binarySearchInput);
```

Comment: or doing `var foundBlog = myBlog[ foundIndex ]` to get the found array, after checking that the index is valid.

Comment: `myBlog[n][0]` represents a Blog Title in OP's domain. And we have no indication that that list is lexically (or other way) sorted in any way. So, while this answer makes the Exception disappear, it will not make any more sense, unfortunately.

Comment: UPDATE: OP uses Bubblesort to sort input. Nevermind my above comment.